# Getting server error 500 on calling a method ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I call a function I get the following error log;
please help decipher it.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `first' for #<Matching:0x0000000875a050>):
  app/mailers/matching_mailer.rb:6:in `new_matchings_for_customer'
  app/models/matching.rb:133:in `block in create_matchings_from_service'
  app/models/matching.rb:126:in `each'
  app/models/matching.rb:126:in `create_matchings_from_service'
  app/models/matching.rb:30:in `process_matchings_for_service'
  app/models/payments/subscription.rb:94:in `find_matchings'
  app/models/payments/subscription.rb:85:in `after_create_actions'
  app/controllers/contractors/subscriptions_controller.rb:51:in `subscribe'
  app/controllers/contractors/subscriptions_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

EDIT 1:

First few lines of matching mailer:

```
class MatchingMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "\"Estimate My Project\" <info@estimatemyproject.com>"
def new_matchings_for_customer(matchings, customer_id)
    @customer = Customer.find(customer_id)
@matchings = Matching.find(matchings)
@category = @matchings.first.emp_request.subcategory.category
unless @customer.email.empty?
  mail(to: @customer.email, subject: "#{@category.name} estimate for project in #{@customer.zip_code.county.name}, #{@customer.zip_code.state.code} #{@customer.zip_code.code}")
else
  self.message.perform_deliveries = false
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `first' for #<Matching:0x0000000875a050>)
```

means that there is no method `first` on a `Matching`.

```
app/mailers/matching_mailer.rb:6:in `new_matchings_for_customer'
```

means you try to call the method `first` on an instance of matching in line 6 of the `app/mailers/matching_mailer.rb``

Looking at your `MatchingMailer` in line 6, we see hat you call `first` on `@matching`. `@matching` was set just the line before. Please note that the `Matching.find` returns one record when you pass in a single `id` and returns an array of records when you pass in a array of `id`s. In this case you pass `matchings` that was provided as an argument to the `new_matchings_for_customer` method.

It is quite obvious, that the `matchings` argument must be a single `id`. Otherwise `@matchings` would have return an array and an array would respond to `first`. Since you always call first and never care about other values in the array, it makes more sense to just load one record.

Change your `MatchingMailer` to:

```
class MatchingMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: '"Estimate My Project" <info@estimatemyproject.com>'

  def new_matchings_for_customer(matching_id, customer_id)
    customer = Customer.find(customer_id)

    if customer.email.present?
      matching = Matching.find(matching_id)
      category = matching.emp_request.subcategory.category

      mail(
        to: customer.email, 
        subject: "#{category.name} estimate for project in #{customer.zip_code.county.name}, #{customer.zip_code.state.code} #{customer.zip_code.code}"
      )
    else
      self.message.perform_deliveries = false
    end
  end
end
```

And ensure to only pass one `matching_id` when calling that method.

Comment: :Added my lines of matching mailer.